# How can I see the whole image?

Tags: html, css

[image]

How can I see the whole image in this particular item? This output image is out of the box. That's why I can't see it. What have to do to see the whole image in this area?

```css
.item .left-part img{
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
}
.item:nth-child(1) .left-part img{
    background: #f0afaf;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
<div class="left-part">
    <img src="./Images/Icons/app.png" alt="">
</div>

<div class="right-part">
    <h4>App Development</h4>
    <p>Get your blood tests delivered at <br> home collect a sample from the <br> news your blood tests.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give Image as a `background` to your `<div class=left-part>`
like `background: url(path).`

You can give `background-size: cover` property to display image in various sizes and constraints.

checkout the following link for all the options
[background-size:property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover)

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. Accidently I used border radius for the image. But it will be for the left part. That's why I can't see the full image. Thanks, everyone.